# How to detect when the screen is on?

Tags: android

As mentioned in a previous question, I am having difficulty intercepting all `android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON` events without a long-lived `Service` (discouraged).

I may be able to work around the need if I can simply work out when the screen is on at any given time, in the `Service`.

Can anyone suggesting a method call that would return this information? 1.5 upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system deliberately doesn't allow applications to receive `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcasts in their manifest, because we very much do not want to have to launch a bunch of apps to turn the screen on or off.  This is something that happens all of the time, and must be as fast as possible.

Unfortunately, as pointed out, there isn't a way to check immediately to see if the screen is on.

Comment: Actually it possible to receive the broadcasts, as BroadcastReceivers on a long-lived Service. My app does this quite happily, but I'm trying to nix the long-lived Service. It just fails silently if you supply it as a intent-filter on a receiver.

Answer (score 5):

`PowerManager.isScreenOn()`
Since: API Level 7

Answer (score 3):

Can the system broadcast of the [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) intent be of any help?

Answer (score 3):

If your code is running, there's a very good chance the screen is on. The main exception would be if your code is woken up via `AlarmManager`.

It would be nice if `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` were a sticky broadcast, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If you can roll with Android 2.1 and newer, `PowerManager` now has an `isScreenOn()` method. The good news is, that's available. The bad news is, since it was added there, it is unlikely that there is any other way to readily determine it. And, a quick inspection of the source code doesn't give much hope that you might hack your way to the information in earlier SDKs.